# How to get the closest img tag in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

#### HTML

"+fileName+"

I need to change the image when the td with `id=fileName` is clicked in jQuery.

How can I fetch the `img` tag and change its `src` attribute using jQuery?

I am trying to do something like this :

```
$($(this).closest("img")).attr("src")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick replies ... helped me solve my issue :)

Answer (score 8):

Use a combination of `.closest` and `.find()`

`closest` finds its **ancestors**

you need to find its descendants and **not the ancestors**

So you need to first find the closest row, which contains the `filename` id element and then `find` the `img` which is a descendant of the corresponding row

```
$(this).closest('tr').find("img").attr("src"); // using find
```

**or**

```
var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'); // get the closest row
$("img", $tr).attr("src");  // use a context to get the image
```

Comment: "the td with id=fileName is clicked". `this` would not contain an `img` at that point, and so find would not entirely work.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `.siblings()`

### JavaScript/jQuery

```
$(this).siblings("#img_id").children('img').prop('src');
```

### Edit

[**JSFiddle proof**](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/7betH/1/)

Answer (score 2):

"the td with id=fileName is clicked": You are going to have to go up to the `tr` element, and then use find to search through the descendants in order to find the image element. `.parentNode` will find the parent element of `this` (the `<td>` in this case). `find("img")` will find the image tag contained in the first `td` element.

```
$($(this.parentNode).find("img")).attr("src")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to clean up your code a bit as you have a random `<span>` and the first `<td>` isn't closed. Your id's need to be wrapped in double quotes.

http://jsfiddle.net/pjdicke/tQ5vr/5/

```
<table>
   <tr class="test_file">
      <td id="img_id"><img src="http://www.abmuku.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/google-logo-small.jpg" /></td>
      <td colspan=2 id="fileName"><button>file name</button></td>
   </tr>
</table>

$('button').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td img').attr('src','http://atoralhistory.uconn.edu/images/Yahoo_logo_small.gif');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
$(this).siblings().find('img').prop('src','your_image_url');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hgnQT/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the `new_src` variable.

```
$(function() {
   $('#fileName').on('click', function() {
      $(this).closest('tr').find('img').attr('src', new_src);
   });
});
```